# How come that nobody could oppose to R' Gamliel in Halachah but could boot him promptly as the President?

Tags: beit-din-court, sanhedrin, nasi

I'm trying to understand the mechanics of the Jewish Presidency as presented in [Berakhot.28a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.28a.2?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en). In the story R"G asks if there is anybody who could object to him in a Halachic issue, and nobody dares. Then he disparages R"Y and "the public" decides to boot him out on the spot.

This behavior seems unrealistic: if nobody can object to him in Halachah, all the more fire him from the presidency (he was Hillel's descendant IIRC), and vice versa, if they could so easily cancel his seat, how come they couldn't oppose to his Halacha?

Comment: I don't understand your logic. They didn't argue on him for halacha but they did argue on him when he disparaged other people. That makes a lot of sense. What is confusing?